# Problem with change admin group name in ESXi AD using Powershell script

Tags: powershell, active-directory, esxi

I tired to use this function to change group in my ESXi AD domain in my Powershell script:

```
Get-VMHost | Get-AdvancedSetting -Name Config.HostAgent.plugins.hostsvc.esxAdminsGroup | Set-AdvancedSetting -Value “GROUPNAME” -confirm:$false
```

but I have error with Get-AdvancedSetting and Set-AdvancedSetting.

The error is: `The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the command either because the command does not take pipeline input or the input and its properties do not match any of the parameters that take pipeline input.`

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: As aside, it is best never to use curly smart-quote thingies in code like you have around `“GROUPNAME”`. Use straight ones.

Comment: What is th eoutput from `Get-AdvancedSetting -Name Config.HostAgent.plugins.hostsvc.esxAdminsGroup` ? The object returned will tell you why it can't be piped to ther Set-AdvancedSetting command